# Ways to apply multiple filters in Adobe Pixelbender?

Tags: actionscript-3, pixel-bender

How to apply multiple filters in Adobe Pixelbender in Flash (=limited version)?
For example 3 different kinds of video displacement effects (1 displacement on the left, one on the right and one the top).
I know, it possible to just copy paste the code multiple times, but this wouldn't be very elegant.

It supposes to apply the second filter after the first filter is applied and the third filter after the second filter is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply pixel bender filters as Shader objects. Then just use:

```
myDisplayObject.filters = [shader1, shader2, shader3, ...etc];
```

Specifically, you use the ShaderFilter object. You can find a complete code sample in the documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ShaderFilter.html#includeExamplesSummary

You can also see a tutorial from Adobe here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS6FCADA8A-C82B-4d55-89AC-63CA9DEFF9C8.html